# Need an explanation for a particular R code snippet

Tags: r, code-snippets, explain

The following is the code for which i need an explanation for:

```
for (i in id) {
data <- read.csv(files[i] )

c <- complete.cases(data)
naRm <- data[c, ]
completeCases <- rbind(completeCases, c(i, nrow(naRm)))
```

as i understand, the variable c here stores multiple logical values. The line after, that seems foreign to me. How does `data[c, ]` work?
FYI, I am an R newbie.

Comment: You should never ever name a variable `c`, because it also the name of [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) pretty important function.

Comment: The line you're talking (naRM <- data[c,]) removes all incomplete cases from the data frame "data". A complete case is a row with no missing values. Whoever wrote this snippet used the name of the obejct "naRm" to indicate that missing values "na" are removed "Rm".

Comment: @MichaelKaiser how does it do that? I mean how does `data[c, ]` work?

Comment: `c` holds a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. Thus indexing into the rows of data with c extracts the `TRUE` values indicating a row no NA values. Then the next line just counts up those values with `nrow`. This could be accomplished more easily with `completeCases <- c(completeCases, sum(complete.cases(data)))`

Comment: Yep, cr1msonB1ade was faster than me!!

Comment: Those variable names are ones to avoid as they overlap with existing functions

Answer (score 0):

complete.classes looks for all rows that are "complete", have no missing values. Here is the [man page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html). Thus the completeCases object will tell you the number of "complete" rows in each file you have just read. You really don't need to store the value of i in the rbind call though as it is just the row number, so it is redundant. A vector would do just fine for this application.

Also looks like you are missing a close brackets or this isn't a complete chunk of code.